# How can I redirect to a user profile if a user enter domain/username

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, amazon-cloudfront

Description:
I need to redirect when the user input
From -> https://example.com/username
To -> https://example.com/profile/profile.php?profileid=12345678

But we still want to show:
https://example.com/username as a friendly url in the browser.

The page will be public so I can't rely on that the user has to login.

Environment I'm using:

- EC2 servers on Amazon
- CloudFront for images
- Nginx WebServers
- MySQL database
- PHP7.2/jQuery/HTML

Thank

Comment: You can describe in more detail your question [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That best enable the community to provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to know if anyone had a general idea about this. What technical solution that was best for this.

I guess tools like F1 and Akana can handle this redirection.

I temporary solved it by using Nginx reverse proxy:

location /username/ {
proxy_pass http://example.com/public/profile.php?id=123/;  # note the trailing slash here, it matters!
}